# How to deploy .net artifacts to JFrog artifactory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, devops, jfrog-mission-control

As JFrog Artifactory provides maven repository which maintains a maven-metadata.xml to get the latest maven artifact.

Is there anything to maintain latest artifacts of .net web applications. It would be good if there's a solution with the trial version.

Thank you

[Dotnet Binaries Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbIKo.png)

Comment: You can check out MSBuild Artifactory Plugin: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/MSBuild+Artifactory+Plugin

Answer (score 1):

On the PRO version of Artifactory you can also create a Nuget repository and deploy your .net files there. See additional information here:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/NuGet+Repositories

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can you tell me how do we maintain versioning for mvc kind of applications? As you know nuget  manages only class libraries.

Comment: not sure I understand your question or if it is related to Artifactory. can you explain please?

Comment: My question is "does artifactory provide me versioning for .net artifacts which end up in .zip extension"

Comment: Do you mean something like the maven snapshots? are you planning that Artifactory will replace XXX with timestamp? I'm sorry but it's still not clear 100%. Please share an example of what exactly you wish to publish and how you want it to be on Artifactory.

Comment: Hey @Ariel have added a image which may clear your confusion. I should have posted it initially.